# how single onclick event of button can perform 2 operations

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How can i make a textbox visible and call a function from external javascript simultaneously, 
by clicking one  single button(on single onclick event)?

right now m using this ,but getting the value of textbox on double click.

```
protected void BtnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblRisk.Visible = true;
        TxtRisk.Visible = true;
        BtnCalculate.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "Javascript:CalculateRisk();");
    }
```

the value of textbox (whose id is 'TxtRisk') comes from the function 'CalculateRisk()'

Comment: Add this `BtnCalculate.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "Javascript:CalculateRisk();");` on page_load

Answer (score 2):

You are attaching javascript event when server side event for button is triggered. You will get he javascript event after first `click`. Attach the `javascript` event before button click could be in `page_load` event.

```
void My_Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BtnCalculate.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "Javascript:CalculateRisk();");
}

protected void BtnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LblRisk.Visible = true;
    TxtRisk.Visible = true;     
}
```

Comment: Error: Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
<asp:Button id="asd" runat="server" onClick="BtnCalculate_Click" onClientClick="CalculateRisk()">
```